# I can/could only hope

Tags: modal-verbs

1. *I **can** only hope I will ever meet someone like you.*
2. *I **could** only hope I would ever meet someone like you.*

Are 1) and 2) both correct? If so, what is the difference between them?

Comment: They are both a little strange. It would be more natural to use *sometime* rather than *ever*, and, semantically, if the person is being addressed, haven't they already met? As such, I would expect it to be: *I [hope to] **sometime** meet someone **else** like you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is correct because the tone is hypothetical.  You would not hear someone ever using the conjugations in 1 as they are more definitive rather than hypothetical.  But as pointed out by Jason, the nature of the sentences are odd because you are already talking to the person of whom you are hoping to meet in the future.  A sentence like 'I had hoped I would meet someone like like you' would make more sense because the hope had occurred in the past before meeting the person.